The key was not found in the key ring and Error unprotecting the session cookie
Hi we have C# application that deploys docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 to azure kubernetes service. We have a service inside AKS called external app that needs to connect to another service over http but its throwing up exception in Azure app insight "The key was not found in the key ring" and in the same exception it says "error unprotecting the session cookie"
when i check the pod it doesnt have any keyring folder. we have also deployed data protection following article here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0 but it doenst pick up the key from our blob storage either and we keep getting "the key was not found"
my question is where is the key coming from? looks like our implementation of data protection has not kicked in
I think if we understand where they is coming from then we can make progress. Please do share where the key actually comes from?

sorry for a flat question with no code but i only need to find out the mechanism that generates the key and how it gets stored in a light weight asp net image etc

Is your app a sample one or does it has any other configurations?

Please share the log traces once.

It’s a production level complex app with all the bells and whistles. Sorry for security reasons I may not be able to share the logs. It will be great if you could share how the key is generated and where it gets stored. I have shared an article where it explains how to store it in blob storage

I want to basically know if we don’t try to store in blob or azure key vault as per article above, how it gets generated by default


I want to basically know if we don’t try to store in blob or azure key vault as per article above, how it gets generated by default

If you don't want any custom storage like Azure blob storage, Azure key vault or Redis. ASP.NET Core chooses the default key storage location based on the operating system/environment.

It works locally fine but its highly recommended to use Azure key vault, Redis or Blob storage as this ensures security and reliability.
Please refer this github doc for better understanding of key management.

I created a simple application that stores the keys by default and storage location depends on the runtime environment.
This is my program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("DataProtectionDemo")
    .AddKeyManagementOptions(options =>
    {        
        options.NewKeyLifetime = TimeSpan.FromDays(90); 
    });
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/protect", (IDataProtectionProvider provider) =>
{
    var protector = provider.CreateProtector("SamplePurpose");
    var protectedData = protector.Protect("Hello World");
    return $"Protected Data: {protectedData}";
});
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello from Data Protection Demo!");
app.Run();

In the above code, the string "Hello from Data Protection Demo!" will be encrypted when accessed via the /protect endpoint using ASP.NET Core’s data protection system.

To find the stored keys,
If the app has access to windows registry, the keys will be stored in

press windows+R and type regedit hit enter
Expand the following path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\DataProtection here the keys are stored.

If you don't see any keys here that means the application doesn't have administrator privileges to write to the registry.
You can see as I don't have admin privileges, I can't see keys here

In these cases, the keys are generally stored in file storage instead.
you can find your keys in below path
C:\Users\<YourUser>\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\



how about if a .net app is deployed in azure kubernetes service using ubuntu image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0. I tried to find keyring folder but it wasnt there at least in the default location.

In Linux-based containers like the Ubuntu image (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0), Data Protection keys are not stored in a "keyring" folder by default. Instead, they are stored in memory. This means they are lost if the container restarts, which can cause issues like the "key not found" error. To avoid this, it’s best to use Azure Blob Storage, Key Vault, or Redis to store the keys so they persist across pod restarts and across multiple instances.
